# Mysql dynamic query in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to this node.js concepts.What i have tried is updating a database and retreiving datas from database(working fine).On further step i returned the output(from database) into an "JSON" format(working fine)..Now my requirement is to have a dynamic query..

Consider:

The following url:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:3002/users will retrieve all datas from users table and return in json format
```

But what i want is:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:3002/users=abcdef so the datas for that particular user should be returned in json format.
```

My code:

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
    connection.query('select * from nodejs where', function(err, rows, fields) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
        //res.render('users', {users: docs});
    });
});
```

So how can i modify the above code to retrieve only for specific users details..Help me to solve this..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new route in your application. You can specify parameters in your URL as

http://xxx.xxx.xx.x:3002/users/fname1

Here fname1 is user Id and you can add the following code to get the parameter from url

```
req.params.fname
```

Here the fname is got the name from the route that defined in your application as:

```
app.get('/users/:fname', function (req, res) {
connection.query("select * from nodejs where fname= '"+req.params.fname+"'", function(err, rows, fields) {
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
//res.render('users', {users: docs});
});
});
```

Use url/:nameOfParameter to specify the name for values in url

Comment: Please, please escape the value before sending it to MySQL, otherwise you'll open your application to SQL injections. See [node-mysql's documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values).

Comment: @PaulMougel you are correct, I just copied code from question.

Comment: Thanks man..But showing this error:--> ComQueryPacket
{ command: 3, sql: 'select * from nodejs where fname=subburaj' }

<-- ErrorPacket
{ fieldCount: 255,
  errno: 1054,
  sqlStateMarker: '#',
  sqlState: '42S22',
  message: 'Unknown column \'subburaj\' in \'where clause\'' }

Comment: If string you should use single quote(') as
connection.query("select * from nodejs where fname= '"+req.params.fname+"'", function(err, rows, fields) {});

Comment: check now. Do't forget to escape the value before sending it to MySQL as @Paul Mougel mentioned